# Save HTML Form Data to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new in saving HTML Form Data to Google Sheet. I am following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a0GX.png) tutorial.

My `Code.gs` is like below

```
// if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
 var TO_ADDRESS = "abcd@gmail.com";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
// uses an array of keys if provided or the object to determine field order
function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  if (!order) {
    order = Object.keys(obj);
  }
  
  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

// sanitize content from the user - trust no one 
// ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)
function sanitizeInput(rawInput) {
   var placeholder = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(" ");
   placeholder.appendUntrusted(rawInput);
  
   return placeholder.getContent();
 }

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);
    
    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }
    
    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;
    
    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // hold off up to 30 sec to avoid concurrent writing
  
  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it
    
    // select the 'responses' sheet by default
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    
    var oldHeader = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var newHeader = oldHeader.slice();
    var fieldsFromForm = getDataColumns(e.parameters);
    var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
    
    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      
      // mark as stored by removing from form fields
      var formIndex = fieldsFromForm.indexOf(field);
      if (formIndex > -1) {
        fieldsFromForm.splice(formIndex, 1);
      }
    }
    
    // set any new fields in our form
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsFromForm.length; i++) {
      var field = fieldsFromForm[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      newHeader.push(field);
    }
    
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // update header row with any new data
    if (newHeader.length > oldHeader.length) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, newHeader.length).setValues([newHeader]);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return;
  }

}

function getDataColumns(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(function(column) {
    return !(column === 'formDataNameOrder' || column === 'formGoogleSheetName' || column === 'formGoogleSendEmail' || column === 'honeypot');
  });
}

function getFieldFromData(field, data) {
  var values = data[field] || '';
  var output = values.join ? values.join(', ') : values;
  return output;
}
```

I am getting `Time` at First column always.  How can I remove that ?

[image]

Comment: The link on the first statment points to the screenshot, not to referred tutorial. By the other hand, instead of postin the whole code you should post a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén, I am new in Google Apps Script. I don't know what to do ? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Thanks @Rubén for your reply. I read your link. But your link is not related to my issue.

Comment: What is your desired output? What are you trying to achieve? Do you not want to return the date column? Do you want to insert this data from the row 2? Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
```

to this:

```
var row = [];
```

That line is declaring the array which will eventually get added to the sheet with `setValues()`, and it's being initialized with a date as the first element of the array. Removing the date from the array declaration will establish an empty array, which will later be populated with `row.push(output);`

Comment: Thanks @Employee. I tried it before but it is not working. Why rows are printing at no `16` ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJpoD.png

Comment: should I do anything after editing the code ? or only Save the code is enough ?

Comment: Saving the code in the Apps Script editor and the submitting the form again should be enough. Also, it's adding the values to the sheet at row 16 because of the line `var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row` just before the line where the values are set. `sheet.getLastRow()` will return the row number of the last (bottom-most) row which has content, and then you're adding one to that. So there must be some characters or whitespace in cells up to row 15. Try first completely deleting rows 2 through 21 and then perform another test.